# Backbone.js collection url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am working on a backbone.js application with rails api which provides the json as shown:

```
   [{
        "title": "Da vinci Code",
        "price": "50"
    },
    {
        "title": "Some other name",
        "price": "45"
    }],
```

TODO:

1. When a user visits the url "**www.backboneapp.com/authors/1"** , it should display a list of books belonging to the author.

Progress: 
 - Server side-Rails **[*authorscontroller#show*]**

```
def show
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @books  = @author.books
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @books }
    format.html
  end
end
```

2.Client-side-Backbone.js

Router:

```
routes: {
  'authors/:id': 'showauthor'
},

showauthor: function(id) {

  $('#container').empty();
  window.available_books = new AvailableBookList({
    id: id
  });

  this.availablebooklistview = new AvailableBookListView({
    id: id,
    collection:  available_books
  });

  $('#container').append(this.availablebooklistview.render().el);
}
```

AvailableBookList Collection:

```
AvailableBookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: AvailableBook,
  url: "/authors/" + this.id  
})
```

The View part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

AvailableBookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:   'section',
  className: 'availablebooklist',

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(available_book) {
      var view = new AvailableBookView({
         model: available_book,
      });

      this.$('.availablebooklist').append(view.render().el);
    });
    return this;
  }
});

});
```

Problem: when i visit  "**www.backboneapp.com/authors/1"** I am getting 404 error.
In console.log it shows:
   get: **www.backboneapp.com/authors/*undefined***

In Rails log: `parameters {id => undefined}`

**Where am i going wrong? **

*Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you didn't mean `new AuthorList` in your router, but rather `new AvailableBookList`.

You have two problems in your collection:

1. In the definition of your url, `this` refers to the `window` object.
2. The `id` parameter you're passing in the constructor is *not* applied to your collection instance. It works this way for views only (not for models nor collections).

To solve the first problem, you can use a function to define a collection url, which would put you in the correct scope:

```
AvailableBookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: AvailableBook,
  url: function() {
    return "/authors/" + this.id;
  }
});
```

For the second one, you can define an `initialize` function and set the `id` attribute in there:

```
AvailableBookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
  },
  model: AvailableBook,
  url: function() {
    return "/authors/" + this.id;
  }
});
```

For readability purposes, I would also suggest renaming `id` to `author_id`:

```
AvailableBookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.author_id = options.author_id;
  },
  model: AvailableBook,
  url: function() {
    return "/authors/" + this.author_id;
  }
});
```

**Update**

You're also initializing your collection in the wrong way. According to the [Backbone.js source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-54), the constructor signature is `models, options`:

```
window.available_books = new AvailableBookList(null, {
  id: id
});
```

Comment: In the `initialize: function(models, options) { this.id = options.id);}` I am getting **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined** , even the author_id solution's giving me the same error.. `initialize: function(options) { this.id = options.id; }`, this works....But I still get the same error **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Thanks as well for the follow-ups, they're also welcome from an answerer point of view.